# how to set size and bound of button which are added on JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

I have written a code in java using swing.So that i will have a JscrollPane added to JPanel n then I will add buttons of fixed size to JPanel in verticle fashion

```
JPanel panel=new JPanel(); 
panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); 
int v=ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS; 
int h=ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS;  
JScrollPane jsp=new JScrollPane(panel,v,h); 
jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600)); 
jsp.setBounds(150,670,850,200); 
frame.add(jsp);
```

then I am adding buttons to it at run time.

```
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)  
{ 
     button[i]=new JButton(); 
     button[i].setBounds(20,y,120,120); 
     button[i].setSize(120,120); 
     button[i].setToolTipText(file[i].toString());        
     button[i].setIcon(Icon); 
     panel.add(button[i]);    
     y=y+140; //initially y=20 so 1st button on x=20,y=20 2nd button on x=20,160
 }
```

I want to add a button one below another...(i.e I am getting a verticle scrollbar)

i.e. button1

```
 button2 

   ' 

   '
```

the problem is the size and bounds of button that I am setting using setsize/preffered size and setbounds is **not affecting size  and position** of button (which are added on panel)at all...

how to do it?
can anybody help me???

Comment: You where given an answer in your original posting on this topic and have yet to reply to it so I won't bother wasting my time here. The answer is still the same, use a proper layout manager. Using setSize() and setBounds() "WILL NOT" work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setMaximumSize ()

Comment: Thanks.....Its working with size using setMaximum size.... but how to set bound?????

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the position and size of the components (*by hand*), the container should not use an LayoutManager, that is, set it as `null` to remove the default manager:

```
    panel.setLayout(null);
    ...
        button[i].setBounds(20, y, 120, 120);
        // setSize is not needed
        ...
        panel.add(button[i]);
```

Comment: great.. thanx.. Wasted a lot of time on those stupid layout managers.. x-(

Answer (score 0):

The size will be determined by the `LayoutManager` and only certain `LayoutManager`'s respect a `Component`'s preferred size.  For example, using a `BorderLayout` and adding the `JButton` to the center (i.e. `BorderLayout.CENTER`) will cause the button to expand to occupy all available space.

From the BoxLayout API: "*BoxLayout attempts to arrange components at their preferred widths (for horizontal layout) or heights (for vertical layout).*".  So in your case all buttons will be made as wide as the widest button.  To avoid this case you could use [`GridBagLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html); there's a tutorial [**here**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

Comment: If you can check my question(in code line 3) I have set layout manager as suugested by other and problem of getting buttons in column n setting a size is solved now only the problem is position of buttons...... Please help me in that

Comment: Apologies - I missed that line.  I've amended my answer; In particularly see the 2nd paragraph.